# Create Registry key and values, disable inheritance set no permissions

Tags: powershell, inheritance, registry, windows-10, acl

I am trying to create a registry key and some values and then turn off  inheritance and set permissions (Actually to no permissions) Is this possible to do as you are creating the keys and values?

I see a lot of posts on setting inheritance to on but not much to turn it off and set no permissions. I realize "why would you want to do this?" but it is a requirement of the partner.

The code below creates the object but seems to do nothing with permissions. While it is not the end state it does nothing because inheritance is turned on. 
So what I need is **disable inheritance and set no permissions.**

```
$ResgistryKeyPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RTestBob"
New-Item $ResgistryKeyPath -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path $ResgistryKeyPath -Propertytype DWORD -Name 
Deny_Write -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null
$AddACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("Domain Admins", "FullControl", "Allow")
$AddACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("auth\me", "FullControl", "ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit", "None", "Allow")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set no permissions"?

Comment: I want the permissions to be blank that is no one has access to the key unless they go in and explicitly take ownership etc.

Comment: Don't do that. It's a stupid requirement that will not solve whatever problem your partner thinks it would, but will create collateral damage along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the answer, Right or wrong from a principal standpoint it does work.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
#Set some variables
$RegistryKeyPath1 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b" 
$RegistryKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices"
 $DisableInheritance=$true
$PreserveInheritanceIfDisabled =$True

 #Create the registry keys
 Try {
 New-Item $RegistryKeyPath1 -Force | Out-Null 
 New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Write -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null 
 New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Read -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null  
 New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Execute -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null   
 New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_All -Value 1 -Force  | Out-Null 
 }

 Catch
 {
 [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('Key exists and an error has occured. Please check the registry manually in this location','Error','OKCancel','Error') ; exit 

  }

 Try {

 #Remove Inheritance - Inheritance is removed from both keys so that if one is done the other will have to be also.
 $acl = Get-Acl $RegistryKeyPath1
 $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($DisableInheritance,  $preserveInheritanceIfDisabled)
 Set-Acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $acl
  $acl1 = Get-Acl $RegistryKeyPath
  $acl1.SetAccessRuleProtection($DisableInheritance, $preserveInheritanceIfDisabled)
  Set-Acl $RegistryKeyPath $acl1

  #Remove Permissions
  $aclPerm1 = get-acl $RegistryKeyPath1
  $aclPerm1.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Authenticated Users") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
 set-acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $aclPerm1
 $aclPerm1.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Administrators") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
 set-acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $aclperm1

  $aclPerm = get-acl $RegistryKeyPath
  $aclPerm.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Authenticated Users") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
  set-acl $RegistryKeyPath $aclPerm
  $aclPerm.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Administrators") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
   set-acl $RegistryKeyPath $aclperm
   [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('Successfully Implemented!','Success','OKCancel','Information')  
   }
  Catch
  {
   [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('An error has occured. Please check the registry manually in this location','Error','OKCancel','Error')  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bob: thanks a lot. I spend hours trying to figure out why my code didn't work. It seems that as you did, a new acl object must be used each time.

I think this is a bad garbage collector from PowerShell. How come you can't recycle variables?

So, this won't work:

1. Run the code the first time on a console. Check the permissions on the keys. They should be fine.
2. Now delete the keys manually and run the code again. They keys will be created, but the permissions won't be assigned.

This is because you are reusing the same variables. I guess it is a bad garbage collector on PowerShell.

I found a better way of avoiding using a lot of variables for the same thing:

- One way would be with functions. So, you can always define your $acl locally.
- The second way is using "Remove-Variable" after finishing the task you do with $acl. For example, on Bob's code you could do this:

  ```
  [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
  #Set some variables
  $RegistryKeyPath1 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b" 
  $RegistryKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices"
  $DisableInheritance=$true
  $PreserveInheritanceIfDisabled=$true

   #Create the registry keys
   Try {
       New-Item $RegistryKeyPath1 -Force | Out-Null 
       New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Write -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null 
       New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Read -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null  
       New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath1 -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_Execute -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null   
       New-ItemProperty -path $RegistryKeyPath -propertyType DWORD -Name Deny_All -Value 1 -Force  | Out-Null 
   }

   Catch
   {
      [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('Key exists and an error has occured. Please check the registry manually in this location','Error','OKCancel','Error') ; exit
   }

   Try {
      #Remove Inheritance - Inheritance is removed from both keys so that if one is done the other will have to be also.
      $acl = Get-Acl $RegistryKeyPath1
      $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($DisableInheritance,  $preserveInheritanceIfDisabled)
      Set-Acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $acl
      Remove-Variable acl

      $acl = Get-Acl $RegistryKeyPath
      $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($DisableInheritance, $preserveInheritanceIfDisabled)
      Set-Acl $RegistryKeyPath $acl
      Remove-Variable acl

      #Remove Permissions
      $acl = get-acl $RegistryKeyPath1
      $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Authenticated Users") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
      set-acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $acl
      $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Administrators") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
      set-acl $RegistryKeyPath1 $acl
      Remove-Variable acl

      $acl = get-acl $RegistryKeyPath
      $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Authenticated Users") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
      set-acl $RegistryKeyPath $acl
      $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]  "Administrators") #Administrators,  SYSTEM, ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
      set-acl $RegistryKeyPath $acl
      Remove-Variable acl
      [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('Successfully Implemented!','Success','OKCancel','Information')  
   }
   Catch
   {
      [System.Windows.forms.MessageBox]::Show('An error has occured. Please check the registry manually in this location','Error','OKCancel','Error')  
   }
  ```

It is not nice, but at least it works. This should be documented somewhere.

vbs **does have** in deed a better garbage collector.